# Changing the Emulator theme?

Tags: android, themes, emulation

I'm trying to change my emulator theme by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the skin. This will not change the theme though. You can see an article [here](http://heikobehrens.net/2011/03/15/android-skins/) which describes how to install skins.

Comment: This article is not available anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can change the theme in android Manifest. Then run it. In emulator you can set skins

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to change the launcher. Download a launcher apk and install it on the emulator

Comment: how can i do this? Sorry for asking this? Because, i'm new to andrid

Comment: Usually you find launchers in android market but that's not possible through the emulator afaik. So I guess you have too google and see if anyone have made their launcher apk available for you to download and install it using adb shell commands, alternative find an open source launcher project and install it through eclipse